# How to pull value with only data but populate only a set number of fields

Tags: sql

How to populate only fields that have values but only show a certain number of them in SQL Pybase?

For SQL Pybase, is there a way I can write a query where I can only display a set number of fields only if it is populated?  For example, I want to query an ID with 10 different fields, but I want the result to only display 3 column of results.  The priority is to take any of the 10 fields that are not null (doesn't matter which field) and display 3 of them.  If there is only 1 field that is not null, out of the 10 fields, it would display the data for column 1, but the other two columns would be null.

```
select id, field1, field2, field3, field4
          , field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10
 from table
 where field1 is not null 
    or field2 is not null 
    or field3 is not null 
    or field4 is not null 
    or field5 is not null 
    or field6 is not null 
    or field7 is not null 
    or field8 is not null 
    or field9 is not null 
    or field10 is not null
```

I expect to see the headers

```
id      result1   result2  result3
abc123     5         7        5
ab123      2         3
```

result1, result2, result3 would have non null values taken from field1 to field10.  But I only need 3 columns of result in any order that are not null.
abc123 has at least 3 fields populated out of 10.
ab123 only has 2 fields populated so only 2 columns are populated with result3 as null

Comment: I haven't heard of "SQL Pybase".  Can you give more information on what this is?  Stack Overflow doesn't have a tag for it either.

Comment: I was wondering that myself... Are you talking SQL Server PolyBase? Or are you talking SQL Sybase?

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. In the example you supplied if you have a row with id: abcd123 has non null values in result4, result5, result6 how is it possible to keep only 3 columns? I think you need to reconsider the problem

Comment: Apologies, I was very unclear.  I meant to say SQL Sybase.

Comment: Here is my sample query and results:  select id, tier, value
from tables
where (tier like ('1%') or tier like ('2%') or tier like ('3%'))
and id in ('abc123')
order by id, tier
id        tier value
abc123 1 100.25
abc123 1 100.75
abc123 1 101
abc123 1 101
abc123 2 100.25
abc123 2 101
abc123 2 101
abc123 2 101
abc123 2 101.25
abc123 2 101.375              I want the results to be                                          
   id        tier value
abc123 1 100.25
abc123 1 100.75
abc123 1 101
abc123 2 100.25
abc123 2 101
abc123 2 101.25    But I this result in 1 row per id